# Vector Subspace Elements

Tags: vector-spaces

Just needed help for this question.

If V is a Subspace. I know you can v1+v2∈V since V is a subspace but can you also say v1-v2∈V?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf{Hint}$: since $V $ is a subspace: if $v\in V $ then $cv\in V$ for any scalar $c $.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $V$ contains all linear combinations of its elements, so if $v_1,v_2 \in V$ then $v_1 - v_2 = v_1 + (-1)v_2 \in V$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A subspace of a vector space contains ( by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace)) all linear combinations of its elements. So,  $$v_1 \in V \quad \mbox{and}\quad v_2 \in V \quad\Rightarrow  \quad av_1+b v_2 \in V \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{K}$$

So  also for $a=1$ and $b=-1$.